# Couldn't detect WiFi from my router

Tags: wireless

I recently installed apache2 in my linux after that my laptop couldn't detect my wifi. i even tried to uninstall total linux from the system and installed it again. It could discover all my neighbouring wifi signals, but not from my router.

Comment: Have you reboot your router yet?

Comment: yes i did, remaining devices are able to detect the wifi signal and working normal its just my laptop couldn't detect the wifi signal from that particular router

Comment: Can you post the output of `iwlist [yourwifidevice] freq`?  Replace `[yourwifidevice]` with the name of your device (i.e. wlan, wlp2s0, etc.).